# What is Wario dropping at the end of Super Mario Land 2 and why?

Tags: super-mario-land-2-6-golden-coins

After defeating Wario he drops something and runs off, but I could never identify what he drops or figure out why he drops it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Back in the early 1990s when I first beat this game I thought he was losing a tooth, which was a common thing to happen to people that got beat up by the protagonist.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [Mario wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Mario_Land_2:_6_Golden_Coins#Story), that's one of his shoes:

> Mario was still able to defeat him in battle. As a result, Wario shrinks and begins crying in defeat, but then **throws one of his shoes at Mario** before making his escape from the castle, with Mario following suit.

And for the reason, as also said by @*TripHound*, that move is considered a [Shoe Slap](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShoeSlap):

> throwing shoes happen to be a common occurrence in some cultures and countries, with some seeing it **as an act of disrespect**.

Comment: The wiki is just someone's interpretation though (rather than an official source), although in this case it seems to be the good one.

Comment: @Clockwork it's a wiki, so it's a several people's consensus and not only "someone", I usually trust them to support my statements.

Answer (score 26):

After being defeated, Wario throws a shoe and flees the throne room.

This is easier to see when playing in color using Super Mario Land 2 DX: 6 Golden Coins

[image]
Screenshot from [video by LETSPLAYmarkus](https://youtu.be/4TkyQfgdpp4?t=308)

Comment: @JohnGordon In some cultures, it's a [form of insult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_shoe-throwing_incidents). Don't know if that's the allusion here.

Comment: A corroboration of the insult is that Wario also seems to be sticking his tongue, another act of disrepect.

Comment: Isn't the DX version of that game a ROM hack and therefore just the interpretation of its creator?

Comment: @TripeHound Interesting that there are no reported incidents between the year 359 and 2008, but ever since, there's been multiples every year...  I wonder if that's just a reporting bias because the one thrown at  George W. Bush was such a high-profile incident and nobody bothered documenting it before that...  Come to think of it, is this a deliberate reference since both Wario and GWB are frequently identified by just the letter W?

Comment: Wait, never mind, this game pre-dates the GWB incident by 16 years, forget that.

Comment: @Ocean yes, [DX version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_Land_2:_6_Golden_Coins#Super_Mario_Land_2_DX:_6_Golden_Coins) it's indeed an hack ROM.